# How to stop my water meter connection leak?

Tags: plumbing, water, leak

Prior to moving into my house two years ago, part of he agreement was that the owners would replace the water main valve. It's been good up until a couple weeks ago. There's drip coming out of it about every 5 seconds. It looks to me like I could put thread seal at that connection. Does that sound reasonable? Or might the problem be worse?

[image]

Comment: I've been looking online. I think my first step should be to call the town and request they fix it, which may entail putting in a new meter. Seems like people with similar issues have been able to do that.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: I contacted the town. After a few days a plumber from the PDW showed up and installed a new meter, so far so good.

Answer (score 1):

Gaskets for water meters are usually made of leather. I would contact the water company and ask if they have the washers and can give you 1 or 2 for the meter, or would they replace them. Sometimes you can turn the compression nuts just a slight amount to tighten the gaskets.

Comment: Crank on it with a wrench. Until that's been done it's not up for discussion, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, you have a shut off valve ahead of the meter.

That fitting appears to be compression fitting. If the threads are leaking you may have some luck with the thread seal. However, if the compression part of the fitting is leaking thread seal will not help. You would have to replace the 90° and the fitting.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There's not much pressure there, if it's only a drop every few seconds. I'd recommend molding flex tape around the joint. You'll want to wire brush and clean the area first.